# invalid UTF-8 data

Tags: coldfusion

I am facing a issue of  invalid UTF-8 data in my application.

Actually whenever i opens my application for editing purpose i get the following error:

**[Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver]Transliteration failed, reason: invalid UTF8 data**

Comment: This is incredibly vague. Could you provide any more detail?

Comment: Let me ask my crystal ball... It says to give at least the application's name, how do you start it, what data are you feeding into it, if that's the complete error message, what version of coldfusion are you using. At the very least. And also, it says that divination and magic do not exist.

Comment: Actually the edit page of my application contains many inputboxes such as RTE(Rich Text Editor),simple textbox,so after the users entered their contents into it,when i am trying to open that page it gives me the below mentioned error:[Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver]Transliteration failed, reason: invalid UTF8 data.so please help me out to fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

Some editors expect your code file to be saved in plain UTF8. An easy way to fix it is to open up the affected code file in Notepad, and then re-save it using Notepad's default encoding. Then you can open it in your favorite editor. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from Nodans

> The DataDirect Oracle Driver that ships with ColdFusion 9 has an error in it. It appears the error is fixed and if you have an agreement with the provider, you can download an update. However, I don't have an agreement so I downloaded fresh Oracle JDBC Drivers to fix the problem. Here's what I did:
>
> Download the drivers here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html

For Details: http://www.nodans.com/index.cfm/2012/6/6/How-to-solve-error-Oracle-JDBC-DriverTransliteration-failed-reason-invalid-UTF8-data